# How does a boolean variable work in Emacs lisp?

Tags: elisp

In my package I have the following:

```
(defcustom foobar-on-exit t
"Boolean variable, enabled by default."
:type 'boolean
:group 'foobar)

(if foobar-on-exit 
    (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'some-message))
```

So I get a message when I close Emacs.

Then in my init.el I set the value of `foobar-on-exit` on `nil`.

```
(setq foobar-on-exit 'nil)
```

After evaluating or restarting, I still got the message while the variable `foobar-on-exit` is still false.

So somewhere I went wrong. Any hint?

Comment: Is this a simple evaluation-order problem? If the `if` statement is in your package, then `foobar-on-exit` will be `t` when that form is evaluated and the message will be added to `kill-emacs-hook` regardless of what you do with the variable afterwards. So if your package is loaded (via autoload or otherwise) prior to the `setq`, you'll always get the message.

Comment: Ah, I get it. :Let's assume the boolean variable is in the package by default true, and that hook will be evalauted. How could I make it false in my `init.el`, then it will be evaluated afterwards in the package?

Comment: Well, if you set it prior to loading the package, it should work as intended, but you may be subject to a "reference to free variable" warning should you byte-compile your init file. The correct sequencing is `defcustom`, `setq`, `if`. The only way to do that is to have the `defcustom` in the package, and the `setq` and `if` in your init file. A better way is to put the `if` in the form that gets added to `kill-emacs-hook`, so it will always use the current value at shutdown time.

Comment: @TreborRude You're right, especially with your last sentence. I added the `if` into a function, that will do evaluating, and I added that function to a hook. Thanks for your suggestion, it's appreciated. Wish I could mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: Now you can, @ReneFroger. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an order-of-evaluation problem. Since the `defcustom` and the `if` are both in the package, and the `setq` is in the init file (presumably some time after the loading of the package), when the package gets loaded (via `autoload` or otherwise), `foobar-on-exit` will be set to `t`, then the `if` form will be evaluated and `some-message` will get added to `kill-emacs-hook`.

The correct sequence of events is `defcustom`, `setq`, `if`. The only way to do that presently is to have both the `setq` and the `if` in your init file.

If you want to leave the `if` in the package, then it needs to be in a function that gets added to `kill-emacs-hook`, that way the current value of `foobar-on-exit` will always be used when emacs is killed.